# Passing compressed JSON through socket in Java

Tags: java, json, sockets

I'm planning to split my current `Java 7` application into server and client side. Server and client side should communicate using sockets.
 **Basically:**

> 1) Client sends request to the server through a port.
>   2) Server generates `JSON` response and sends that response back.
>   3) Client should deserialize `JSON`.

Now, the problem is that response `JSON` is about **`1MB`** in size! I have a limited experience with Java sockets and also *communication with server needs to be language-agnostic* so I'm not sure which type of stream should I use?

May I use **`GZipOutputStream`** (if produced results can be unzipped by `GZIP` lib from any language)? Should I use something else?

Please give me some advice :)

Comment: What is your client? If it's a Java application, there is no problem. If it's a browser, you have to check if they can receive a gzip compressed stream. Most can, but IE is a bit buggy with it.

Comment: Currently it's Java app, but it may change

Comment: Any language can communicate over sockets. Your responsability as *solution architect* is to identify what must be exchanged and specify the full protocol, taking care of security concerns (if applicable), possible failures in one side or in network and error recovery. The gzip compression of a json is perfectly acceptable in a heterogeneous environment, but is just one among many things to specify.

Answer (score 1):

If plain socket is the only option then yes, using GZIPOutputStream is a good solution. It will generate a gzip format that is standards-compliant and thus readable by any language or tool supporting the gzip compression format.

If your client is java as well, you can use GZIPInputStream to decompress and get the json text back out.

A challenge will be implementing the socket server and (to lesser extent) the socket client code. I recommend to google for code examples and adjust them to your need.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use http protocol instead of plain socket. Implement your server on an application server, such [tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) or jetty. They are very easy to setup up.

To implement the client side, you can use apache http client.

An advantage of this approach is: You don't need to program http compression. [You can configure it in tomcat](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/enable-gzip-compression-in-tomcat/). The http client will automatically decompress for you.

Comment: I was considering that, but currently it's not an option :( I'm stuck with sockets for the moment

Comment: Hmm..., HTTP has one big quality it is a standard. But it also has big caveats for dedicated use cases: it is often accessible from the outside (when security is a concern), and it is a disconnected protocol (no way to know if peer has *closed* connection). Unsure it would be a good choice here...

Comment: It is your decision, you *can* use sockets for sure. The problem with that approach is that you will need to implement a socket server that can deal with multiple and possible parallel connection requests. This is really no easy matter. There is a very good reason why application servers like tomcat are so popular - using them saves you tremendous amounts of time!